# 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-layout

I am implementing a mousewheel event in tkinter

```
def on_mousewheel(event,canvas):
    canvas.yview_scroll(event.delta,"units")

canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", lambda event:on_mousewheel(event,canvas))
```

It gives me the error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

I am using MacOS. If I drag the scrollbar everything is fine. if I try to use the Mac trackpad or other mouse to scroll, the tkinter shuts down giving me the above error

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem? got the same here. I am sing OSX 10.14, Python 3.7.3 , Tcl 8.5 and Tk 8.5

Comment: No I did not. I dropped that feature then :(